# Javascript - group array of objects by common values with label

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to turn an array of objects into another array of objects by grouping by a specific value and adding that value as label and taking it out of the object in the new array.

**Input:** So for instance I have this array of objects:

```js
let tech = [
  { id: 1, grouping: "Front End", value: "HTML" },
  { id: 2, grouping: "Front End", value: "React" },
  { id: 3, grouping: "Back End", value: "Node" },
  { id: 4, grouping: "Back End", value: "PHP" },
];
```

**Expected:** I am looking to try and figure out how I can get to this, where there is a label for each of the unique groupings and options array containing the values of that grouping.

```js
[
  {
    label: "Front End",
    options: [
      { id: 1, value: "HTML" },
      { id: 2, value: "React" },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Back End",
    options: [
      { id: 3, value: "Node" },
      { id: 4, value: "PHP" },
    ],
  },
]
```

The closest I have been able to get to is using reduce to group by the grouping key:

```js
const groupedTech = tech.reduce((acc, value) => {
  // Group initialization
  if (!acc[value.grouping]) {
    acc[value.grouping] = [];
  }
 
  // Grouping
  acc[value.grouping].push(value);
 
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Which gives me this:

```js
{
  "Front End": [
    { id: 1, grouping: "Front End", value: "HTML" },
    { id: 2, grouping: "Front End", value: "React" },
  ],
  "Back End": [
    { id: 3, grouping: "Back End", value: "Node" },
    { id: 4, grouping: "Back End", value: "PHP" },
  ],
}
```

But this returns object not an array and doesn't remove the grouping value. I have not been able to figure out how to group properly because in the array of objects I have not found an efficient way to compare against to see if the grouping exists and if so add to that nested array. Would I be better off using something like [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? Appreciate any leads/learnings!

Comment: What determines the final ordering? First label encountered?

Comment: Do you want the `id` values to start at `1` for each `label`? That's not what most of the answers do...

Comment: @Nick apologies that was a typo, the ids should have been be 3 and 4 not 1 and 2 again like I had in my original post. Thats my mistake!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're very close, just wrap the key-value entries of the result you've got in a `map` function:

```js
let tech = [
  { id: 1, grouping: "Front End", value: "HTML" },
  { id: 2, grouping: "Front End", value: "React" },
  { id: 3, grouping: "Back End", value: "Node" },
  { id: 4, grouping: "Back End", value: "PHP" },
];

const groupedTech = Object.entries(
  // What you have done
  tech.reduce((acc, { id, grouping, value }) => {
    // Group initialization
    if (!acc[grouping]) {
      acc[grouping] = [];
    }
    
    // Grouping
    // FIX: only pushing the object that contains id and value
    acc[grouping].push({ id, value });

    return acc;
  }, {})
).map(([label, options]) => ({ label, options }));

console.log(groupedTech);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to do one more manipulation with `Object.entries` and `.map`

```js
let tech = [
  { id: 1, grouping: 'Front End', value: 'HTML' },
  { id: 2, grouping: 'Front End', value: 'React' },
  { id: 3, grouping: 'Back End', value: 'Node' },
  { id: 4, grouping: 'Back End', value: 'PHP' }
]

const groupedTech = tech.reduce((acc, value) => {
  // Group initialization
  if (!acc[value.grouping]) {
    acc[value.grouping] = []
  }

  // Grouping
  acc[value.grouping].push(value)

  return acc
}, {})

const res = Object.entries(groupedTech).map(([label, options]) => ({
  label,
  options
}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

A minor variation on the other two answers if you want to get *exactly* the output you specify:

```js
let tech = [{
    id: 1,
    grouping: "Front End",
    value: "HTML"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    grouping: "Front End",
    value: "React"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    grouping: "Back End",
    value: "Node"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    grouping: "Back End",
    value: "PHP"
  },
];

const groupedTech = Object.entries(
    tech.reduce((acc, value) => {
      // Group initialization
      if (!acc[value.grouping]) {
        acc[value.grouping] = [];
      }

      // Grouping
      acc[value.grouping].push({
        id: acc[value.grouping].length+1,
        value: value.value
      });

      return acc;
    }, {}))
  .map(([label, options]) => ({
    label,
    options
  }));

console.log(groupedTech);
```

Comment: Nice pickup on the IDs but probably not what OP wants 

Comment: Yeah, thought the `id` of the expected answer might just be a typo.

Comment: @Phil yeah, as I say, this will produce the expected output from the question but it does seem that isn't what they actually want. I've requested clarification to be sure...

Comment: Hi all yes sorry that was a typo, I fixed it in my question. I don't need each options array to start with 1. Apologies :) Thank you all for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

I usually like to build up a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of key / value pairs then transform those entries into the final result (usually using `Array.prototype.map()` or [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)).

```js
const tech = [
  { id: 1, grouping: "Front End", value: "HTML" },
  { id: 2, grouping: "Front End", value: "React" },
  { id: 3, grouping: "Back End", value: "Node" },
  { id: 4, grouping: "Back End", value: "PHP" },
];

const groupedMap = tech.reduce((map, { grouping, ...option }) => {
  if (!map.has(grouping)) {
    map.set(grouping, [])
  }
  map.get(grouping).push(option)
  return map
}, new Map())

const groupedTech = Array.from(groupedMap, ([ label, options ]) => ({
  label,
  options
}))

console.log(groupedTech)
```

Comment: your ids are `1 ,2` and `3,4` bt he wants it like `1,2` and `1,2`

Comment: @Ifaruki I'd be very surprised if that's what OP actually wants (given the answer they've already accepted)

Comment: well he should then be more precise

Comment: sorry all! was a typo. thats on me! should have been 1,2,3,4 originally. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Using a Map and Map#values()

```js
const grouped = tech.reduce((m,{grouping:label, ...rest})=>{
    const group = m.get(label) || {label, options:[]};
    group.options.push({...rest})
    return m.set(label, group)
},new Map)

console.log([...grouped.values()])
```

```html
<script>
let tech=[{id:1,grouping:"Front End",value:"HTML"},{id:2,grouping:"Front End",value:"React"},{id:3,grouping:"Back End",value:"Node"},{id:4,grouping:"Back End",value:"PHP"}];
</script>
```

Comment: That's nice... really compact.