# Loop over the array and display the following format

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

My goal is to loop over some data and get something like the following output, so if anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated. In order to display something like this, I tried looping something and displaying it in a loop.

```
 let selectedOrders: {code?: string;selectedList?: [{ name: string; language: string }];
  let set = new Set();

      order.orders.map((list) => {

            if (!set.has(list.code)) {
                selectedOrders.push({
                  code: list.code,
                  selectedList: [
                    {
                      name: list.name!,
                      language: list.language!,
        
                    },
                  ],
                });
                set.add(list.serviceCode);
                return;
            }
            selectedOrders.push({
              selectedList: [
                {
                
                      name: list.name!,
                      language: list.language!,
        
                
                },
              ],
            });
        }
      });
 

  return selectedOrders;
});
```

Input

```
{
    code:"A"
    name:"php"
    desc:"language"
    order:2
    },
    {
    code:"A"
    name:"javascript"
    desc:"language"
    order:1
    
    },
```

Output

```
code: A 
   selectedList: [{
    name:"javascript"
   desc:"language"
    },
    {
    name:"php"
   desc:"language"
    }]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787449/javascript-group-array-of-objects-by-common-values-with-label

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = [
      {
        code: "A",
        name: "php",
        desc: "language",
        order: 2,
      },
      {
        code: "B",
        name: "c++",
        desc: "language",
        order: 3,
      },
      {
        code: "A",
        name: "javascript",
        desc: "language",
        order: 1
      }];

    let result = data.reduce((acc: any[], item) => {
      const { name, desc, order, code } = item;
      if (acc.some((a: any) => code == a.code)) {
        let obj: any = acc.find((a: any) => code == a.code)!;
        obj.selectedList.push({
          name, desc, order
        });
      } else {
        acc.push({
          code,
          selectedList: [{ name, desc, order }]
        });
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    console.log(result);
```

Just change any to your required type.